# How to resume downloading if proxy doesn't support HTTP Range requests

Tags: c#, http, curl, request, range

Is there a way to resume downloading from break point if proxy doesn't support HTTP Range requests? Ideally to do it using curl or c#.

Answer (score 1):

No. By definition, if the proxy won't let you pass through a range request, then you cannot do a range request.

The very closest you could get to that would be to just eat X octets rather than do anything with them, but the performance benefit of ignoring those octets is going to pale in comparison to the network connection, unless you'd been doing something really heavy with the stream.

Edit: It's worth noting, that it's always possible for a range-request to be responded to with a 200 instead of a 206, so code that does partial downloads should always be prepared to deal with a full download being sent.